# Invoke a swift function from WKWebView

Tags: swift, wkwebview, ios13, ios12

I am rendering a webpage in WKWebView, and in that webpage, i need to override one button action with a native swift code.Like in webpage on click of a button it navigates to another page, but in mobile, I need a storyboard to be displayed. I am not getting any direct links to implement this. below is the code sample i tried:

```
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let userController = WKUserContentController()

    userController.add(self, name: "performClick")

    webConfiguration.userContentController = userController

    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)

    webView.uiDelegate = self

    webView.navigationDelegate = self

    view = webView
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call a swift function from java script that returns a value using wk webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632957/call-a-swift-function-from-java-script-that-returns-a-value-using-wk-webview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search, I finally got the answer. Posting this if this helps someone.

```
var webView: WKWebView?
var webConfig:WKWebViewConfiguration {
    get {

        let webCfg:WKWebViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let userController:WKUserContentController = WKUserContentController()
        userController.add(self, name: "submit")
        let js:String = buttonClickEventTriggered()
        let userScript:WKUserScript =  WKUserScript(source: js, injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: false)
        userController.addUserScript(userScript)
        webCfg.userContentController = userController;
        return webCfg;
    }
}
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: webConfig)
    self.webView!.navigationDelegate = self
    self.view = webView!
    let url = URL(string:"your URL here")
    let req = NSURLRequest(url:url! as URL)
    self.webView!.load(req as URLRequest)
 }
func buttonClickEventTriggered() ->String{
    
    let script:String = "document.getElementById('your button id here').addEventListener('click', function () {window.webkit.messageHandlers.submit.postMessage('submited');});"//Make sure you have mapped the name correctly under userController.add
    return script;
}
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    print("Sucessss")
    if(message.name == "submit") {
        print("It does ! \(message.body)")
        // Your code goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override [`decidePolicyFor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455641-webview), which is a delegate method of `WKNavigationDelegate`:

```
override func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, 
    decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, 
    decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if <navigationAction is the button press> {
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
         // go to the new storyboard
    } else {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

To decide whether `navigationAction` is the button press, you can inspect its `request` property, which is a `URLRequest`. You should know what `URLRequest` the button sends.

Comment: Thankyou...
Comparing the navigation action URL worked for me
let url = navigationAction.request.url!
 if url.absoluteString.contains("https://.....")
{}

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some part, To listen message from web page you need to make some changes in your web page also. Here are the step to listen some action from webpage, my code snippet are in objective c, you can translate to swift

1. Add your script message using `addScriptMessageHandler` function, it will take param `WKScriptMessageHandler` and message name, for test use message name like, "test"
2. implement `didReceiveScriptMessage` delegate.

   ```
   - (void)didReceiveScriptMessage:(WKScriptMessage*)message {
        if ([message.name isEqualToString: @"test"]) {
           //Do here whatever you want.
        }
   }
   ```
3. On your server page whenever that button pressed call this line.

> webkit.messageHandlers.test

Comment: I have this already but didReceiveScriptMessage never gets invoked

Comment: did you perform step 3- On your server page whenever that button pressed call this line.