# Synchronous Conecction Swift and Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, synchronous

I want to know if exist some method to call a swift function from JavaScript function using synchronous communication like Android, if exist please explain me to Dummies.

Comment: Hi Eicus ,
this link may help full to you :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851630/javascript-synchronous-native-communication-to-wkwebview