# Segue/Navigate to View Controller from UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I have a webview on view controller that load a page consist of list of item.
If I click on each item, I want to navigate into spesific view controller and bypass an id from item's link.

Right now I have no clue how to do this. Is this even possible?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is entirely possible. You need to use a `URL Scheme` to communicate from JavaScript to native code.

A `URL Scheme` allows you to pass data from JavaScript to native code like this:

```
window.location = 'yoururlscheme://somehost?greeting=hello'
```

You receive this event using `UIWebViewDelegate`, where you can fire a segue, or whatever you want.

See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36144481/1305067