# How to access UIWebView's child window context

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have an application (app A) that is running in a UIWebView wrapper. I have another application (app B) that needs to be shown and accept some data from the first one. Currently we are detecting `window.open` (from app A) in the wrapper and creating a new controller with second WebView that slides in and contains app B.

In app A's JS code:

```
var appBWindow = window.open("APP_B_URL");

// Checking inside of setInterval for existence 
// of the .init() that is set by app B on its window
// when it's found we call it and pass it some data
function onAppBWindowLoad() {
   appBWindow.init(someData);
}
```

This works fine on both desktop and iOS Safari, but using UIWebView `appBWindow.init` never changes. It looks like the `JSContexts` was not connected the same way as they are in Safari/Chrome.

Is there a way how to make sure the `appBWindow` works the same as it would in a regular browser?

Answer (score 0):

By app A and app B, are you taking about two different iOS apps? Or two different web views *inside the same iOS app*? I assume you're talking about the latter.

Web views in the same app share the same `sessionStorage`, you can use that to share data. To call functions between web views, you use the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(_:)` method.

**E.g.:**

Swift

```
let result = myWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("onAppBWindowLoad()")
```

where `onAppBWindowLoad` has this implementation:

```
function onAppBWindowLoad() {
    return someData
}
```

**Note**: You may find [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851630/javascript-synchronous-native-communication-to-wkwebview) here useful.

Comment: Yes, sorry, both app A and app B are JavaScript apps inside of the WebView. I know about `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` and I am now using it as a workaround. I also managed to implement a better solution using JSContext but I still think there should be a simple way how to "connect" these 2 WebViews so they can share JS context the same way as browser windows/tabs do when you use `var child = window.open(...)` (on the same domain)