# Javascript call to Swift from UIWebView

Tags: javascript, swift, uiwebview, ios10

I am trying to make a call from a javascript function in a UIWebView to Swift in iOS 10. I have setup a very basic project just to try and get this working, the code is below.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate  {    
  @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "products", withExtension: "html")
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
    }

    @IBAction func closeDocumentViewer() {
        displayView.isHidden = true;
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

If I just one to receive a string from a javascript function what would I have to add to the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must a custom `URL Scheme` such as `myawesomeapp` and intercept requests to it using:

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
```

Fire a call to native code using `window.location=myawesomeapp://hello=world`, and get the query params you pass from `request.URL.query` in the native code.

For more information, see my question about `UIWebView`s here: [JavaScript synchronous native communication to WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851630/javascript-synchronous-native-communication-to-wkwebview)

Comment: how do u get the params in the swift?

Answer (score 20):

I would suggest looking into using `WKWebView` instead `UIWebView`. You then won't need to register custom URL scheme. Additionally, UIWebView is obsolete and WKWebView has a lot of advantages, most notably performance and rendering as it runs in a separate process.

Link to Apple documentation and recommendation to use WKWebView
https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview/

> **Important**
>
> Starting in iOS 8.0 and OS X 10.10, use WKWebView to add web content to your > app. Do not use UIWebView or WebView.

That said, it's very simple to setup a native to javascript bridge:

```
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler {
   var webView: WKWebView?
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        
        webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
        webView?.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "scriptHandler")
        
        self.view.addSubview(webView!)
    }
    
    public func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        print("Message received: \(message.name) with body: \(message.body)")
    }
// rest of code
}
```

Then in your javascript code, call it:

```
window.webkit.messageHandlers["scriptHandler"].postMessage("hello");
```

I have written a library that leverages this and adds some fancy javascript syntax.
https://github.com/tmarkovski/BridgeCommander

To use it, just reference the project (or add the swift and javascript files to your Xcode project) and call

```
    webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
    let commander = SwiftBridgeCommander(webView!)
    
    commander.add("echo") {
        command in
        command.send(args: "You said: \(command.args)")
    }
```

You then will be able to use callback syntax in javascript like this

```
var commander = new SwiftBridgeCommander();
commander.call("echo", "Hello", function(args) {
        // success callback
    }, function(error) { 
        // error callback
});
```

Comment: i was using wkwebview, but wkwebview can lead to dead ends. Like it is not syncing cookie with nshttpcookiestrorage

Comment: Yup, that's one downside of WKWebView. It runs the web engine in isolated process and has no access to your runtime memory.

Comment: Check the WKWebsiteDataStore documentation for cookie management with WKWebView - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebsitedatastore

Comment: It doesn't expose any method to access cookie prior to iOS 11

Comment: Much appreciated @Dr.Kameleon

Answer (score 0):

We can call the swift function from Javascript with the help of **WKScriptMessageHandler**

A class conforming to the WKScriptMessageHandler protocol provides a method for receiving messages from JavaScript running on a webpage.

we need to add a listener to the event into our WKUserContentController

```
 let contentController = WKUserContentController()
    contentController.add(self, name: "loginAction”)
```

We have to implement its userContentController to receive the content sent from Javascript. for ex. limiting only to the "logout" we want for now.

```
  func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {       
       if message.name == "logout" {
           print("JavaScript is sending a message \(message.body)")
       }
   }
```

And from JavaScript end, They have to implement like this:

```
 function sendLogoutAction() {
       try {
           webkit.messageHandlers.logout.postMessage("logout");
       } catch(err) {
           console.log('The native context does not exist yet');
       }
    }
```

Comment: I think that in your case `didReceive message` will never be triggered since your "keys" `logout`(JS side) and `loginAction`(Swift) do not match. Correct me if I am wrong.