# Return result from called function in iOS to calling function in WkWebView in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

We called a function in iOS from javascript i.e

```
var data = webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage("Hello from JavaScript");
```

I want to assign returned value in data variable from called method in iOS.

iOS Code :

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if(message.name == "callbackHandler") {
            print("JavaScript is sending a message \(message.body)")
            how to send data back??
        }
    }
```

can someone please tell me how to do it??

I know I can use **evaluateJavascript** to call back another method but due to some restriction I have to return result  from same method.

Comment: I think this is essentially a duplicate of [my question a few years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851630/javascript-synchronous-native-communication-to-wkwebview). Unfortunately there haven't been any answers yet.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach:

Javascript:

```
function callNativeCode() {
    webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage("Hello from JavaScript");
}

// this function will be later called by native code
function callNativeCodeReturn(returnedValue) {
    // do your stuff with returned value here
}
```

Swift:

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    if(message.name == "callbackHandler") {
        print("JavaScript is sending a message \(message.body)")
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("callNativeCodeReturn(0)")
    }
}
```

Of course this is not very elegant and not synchronous...

There is another approach with promises, you can find out more about it here: 
http://igomobile.de/2017/03/06/wkwebview-return-a-value-from-native-code-to-javascript/

Comment: Is there a way to integrate the promise uuid generator into the `Promise` class itself? Even better if done in a transparent way without having to use a different class, but rather using the same `new Promise(...)` constructor.

Comment: It's strongly discouraged to modify the prototypes of standard JavaScript objects.
But it is possible (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp)

Answer (score 2):

iOS 14+ adds a "didReceive:replyHandler" parameter, which can contain a 'reply' object or an 'errorMessage'. This 'replyHandler' is effectively a formal implementation of the above 'evaluateJavaScript' async callback:

Apple documentation for [WKScriptMessageHandlerWithReply interface](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkscriptmessagehandlerwithreply?language=objc) and [didReceive:replyHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkscriptmessagehandlerwithreply/3585111-usercontentcontroller)

For an example using this 'replyHandler', see this StackOverflow post: [iOS 14 API WKScriptMessageHandlerWithReply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65270083/how-does-the-ios-14-api-wkscriptmessagehandlerwithreply-work-for-communicating-w)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get data in JS from Swift, asynchronously, you may also use `localStorage`.

In Swift :

```swift
webView.evaluateJavaScript("localStorage.setItem(\"mykey\",\"myval\")")
```

In JS :

```js
let myval = localStorage.getItem('mykey')
```

Answer (score -1):

You could give the `WebViewJavascriptBridge` library a try and see if it fits your needs.

https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge.